# Vertically center a float in the remaining part of a page

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment

How do I vertically center a table in the remaining part of a page? Specifically, I want to put a large table on a single page but I also want to have a subsection title line at the top. However, using the below code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Title}
\begin{figure}[p]\centering\begin{tabular}{c}
test\\
\end{tabular}\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

puts the table vertically centered, but on a new page.

Of course, others may want to have several paragraphs followed by a single float centered vertically in the remaining area of the page. So one wonders if there is a way to easily accomplish this?

Comment: the `[p]` option for `figure` always goes to a new page, and doesn't allow anything else on that page. `[b]` will move the float to the bottom of the page, so that's not what you want either.  in this case, you should probably try using just `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` and not treat it as a float at all, but add vertical space manually as necessary.

Comment: What about `\vfill\begin{figure}\centering ... \end{figure}\vfill` or am I missing something?

Comment: That does not work (for me). It puts the table at the top with the subsection title following right after.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `\vfill` with `\vspace*{\fill}`?

Comment: That actually does the same as \vfill, at least for me.

Comment: @laissezfaire Actually it works at the beginning or at the end of a page too, where `\vfill` and the unstarred `\vspace` get ignored.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A float environment is hardly warranted here, since you seem to require a specific location for your `tabular` environment. Why not just do the following?

See [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Floats) for more details on what floats are used for.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Foobar}

Please refer to Table~\ref{fig:mytable} for more details.

\lipsum[1]

\vspace*{\fill}
{
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c} 
  28 & 1 & (1)(28) & 28 \\
  27 & 0 & (0)(27) &  0 \\
  26 & 1 & (1)(26) & 26 \\
  25 & 2 & (2)(25) & 50 \\
  24 & 3 & (3)(24) & 72 \\
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{A magnificent table}
\label{fig:mytable}
}
\vspace*{\fill}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: two problems here: if any text comes after this, it will be centered unless `\centering` is turned off or "buried" in a group; also, if the following text, or the first paragraph, would fit on the page, *it will go on the same page*.  it would be good to add `\clearpage` or `\newpage` after the second fill.